# SQL Developer: choose the tablespace where a new table will be stored

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

When creating a new table, is it possible to specify the tablespace where the table is going to be stored?

Comment: Are you using the GUI or typing out the DDL in a Worksheet?

Answer (score 3):

Check `Advanced`, and under `Storage`, `Define Storage`, where you can choose the tablespace.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#ADMIN11004)  you can specify the tablespace via the `CREATE TABLE` command:

```
CREATE TABLE hr.admin_emp ( 
    empno NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY
    , ename VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL
    , ssn NUMBER(9) ENCRYPT
    , job VARCHAR2(10)
    , mgr NUMBER(5)
    , hiredate DATE DEFAULT (sysdate)
    , photo BLOB
    , sal NUMBER(7,2)
    , hrly_rate NUMBER(7,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (sal/2080)
    , comm NUMBER(7,2)
    , deptno NUMBER(3) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT admin_dept_fkey 
        REFERENCES hr.departments (department_id)
) TABLESPACE admin_tbs 
   STORAGE ( INITIAL 50K); 

COMMENT ON TABLE hr.admin_emp IS 'Enhanced employee table';
```